# Cant install PyAudio python3.8

Tags: python, pyaudio

I have kali linux, amd64, last python3.8 version, and when i am trying to install pyaudio i get just this                                                                                                                                                         `ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio Running setup.py clean for PyAudio Failed to build PyAudio Installing collected packages: PyAudio Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l87_4qp_/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l87_4qp_/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-2u86ewfj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/PyAudio                                                                                                     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-l87_4qp_/PyAudio/                                                                                                                                                                 Complete output (16 lines):                                                                                                                                                                                  running install                                                                                                                                                                                              running build                                                                                                                                                                                                running build_py                                                                                                                                                                                             creating build                                                                                                                                                                                               creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8                                                                                                                                                                          copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8                                                                                                                                                         running build_ext                                                                                                                                                                                            building '_portaudio' extension                                                                                                                                                                              creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8                                                                                                                                                                         creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src                                                                                                                                                                     x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/_portaudiomodule.o                                        src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: Нет такого файла или каталога                                                                                                                        29 | #include "portaudio.h"                                                                                                                                                                               |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                               compilation terminated.                                                                                                                                                                                      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1                                                                                                                                              ----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l87_4qp_/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-l87_4qp_/PyAudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-2u86ewfj/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.8/PyAudio Check the logs for full command output`
Idk what to do with that

Comment: You'll need to paste the output before that too, or the contents of the logs mentioned.

Comment: @AKX edited, added log

Comment: You seem to be missing the portaudio development headers. Try `apt install libportaudio-dev` or similar first.

Comment: @AKX sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev helped

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing portaudio19-dev